# How to separate rows of cells in a matrix using logical indexing?

Tags: matlab, matrix, cell

```
l2 = [{'walk', 'water', 'warm', 'cheer', 'word', 'happy', 'whim', 'womb', 'wear', 'well'};
{'hello', 'here', 'hat', 'that', 'happy', 'hide', 'awesome', 'there', 'howl', 'harry'};
{'look', 'listen', 'lyer', 'hateful', 'lost', 'hatred', 'plot', 'player', 'plow', 'lay'};
{'goat', 'meat', 'hope', 'house', 'love', 'wall', 'down', 'up', 'sky', 'mount'};
{'go', 'golf', 'loser', 'gyrus', 'terrible', 'gallore', 'tug', 'thor', 'gear', 'leg'}];
```

So I have this data above, and I want to be able to separate each row in terms of it being either positive or negative. 
As you can see above: My first row has 2 positive targets amongst neutral words and the third row has 2 negative targets amongst neutral words.

Now if I was running this where the participant saw each word in a sequence per row, how can I get an accuracy for their response to a row with positive targets vs negative target?

Any ideas?
Please help, I just cant figure it out

So far I was thinking of using logical indexing to separate positive targets and negative target, but how do I do that with cell rows?

I have this:

```
positive_t = [1 1; 1 1; 0 0; 1 1; 0 0]
```

This above denotes all the positive targets as 1 and negative targets as 0 but how would I be able to separate them properly row by row? Also. Then if I want to find how many time the participants got the answer for positive row vs negative row. How can I save the accuracy of that?

Comment: You need some dictionary which contains words that are positive, and one that contains words that are negative. Then you simply use [`ismember`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html): `ismember(l2,dictionary)`

Comment: How do I make that dictionary? Can you please help me?

Comment: No. I cannot help you. You'd need to copy the entire Oxford dictionary and say for each word whether it's positive, neutral or negative. Seems like a lot of work to me, but since you cannot determine by other ways (perhaps advanced Neural Network or machine-learning) what you are looking for, this is the way to go imho.

Comment: But thats too much work. All I need to do is separate those CERTAIN positive and negative targets. I can accomplish it through logical indexing, i just dont know how and i need help with that.

Comment: You can only use logical indexing *if* you have a dictionary. Just make a small one containing only the certain words you need and neglect the rest of the language in that case.

Comment: when you say dictionary. What do you mean? I recognize dictionaries from python but i dont know how it is in MATLAB

Comment: You create some cell array `positive` which contains positive words, some cell array `negative` which contains negative words etc.

Comment: @user2924450 just a heads up: there are no python-like dictionaries in matlab, Adriaan was only referring to a concept. Use a cell array listing the positive words, a cell array listing the negative ones, etc, as he suggested.

Comment: @AndrasDeak I was referring to the things I have as physical entities made of paper lying on my book shelves. Those contain words in an alphabetical order and explain or translate the meaning of those words. That's the dictionary I grew up with.

Comment: @user2924450, another heads up: Adriaan doesn't speak any python.

Comment: Well there is an actual dictionary in python and its much like a cell array so i just wanted some confirmations. Thanks guys

Comment: @user2924450 just to be clear now: did Adriaan's comment about `ismember` solve your question? Where are you at now?

Comment: Just a comment in general: text processing is not a strongpoint of Matlab. If I had a big Natural Language Processing (NLP) project, I probably would use something else.

Answer (score 0):

I assume 1) you want to test a person's ability to pick out positive or negative words and 2) you already have a standard answer ( as your test standard ) that you're going to compare testee's answer against.

I don't know what your definition of positive is, so I'm also being tested by you in a sense, but let's assume that you have this standard answer :

```
std_answer = logical([ 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1;...  % 'happy' and 'well'
               0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0;...          % 'happy' and 'awesome'
               0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0;...          % 'hateful' and 'hatred'
               0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0;...          % 'hope' and 'love'
               0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 ]);          % 'loser' and 'terrible'
```

The `std_answer` here is an logical array that has the same number of elements as your `l2`. It has value of 1 wherever your answer is ( which of course, as a tester you already know. Here I'm just taking some guess and assume the standard answer to make an example) and 0 otherwise.

You can apply this mask to your `l2` and the result will be your answers

```
answers = l2(std_answer);
```

If you really wish to do it row by row, of course you can do this:

```
for ii = 1:size(l2, 1)
    sublist = l2(ii, :);
    submask = std_answer(ii, :);
    answer = sublist(submask);
end
```

At the end of the test, you'll have a testee response ( let's say you named it test_response) that's also a 5*10 logical array. You can compare the testee response to standard answer by using logical operation:

```
score = test_response & std_answer ;
```

`score` will also be a logical array whose 1 indicate a match between testee response and standard answer.